# Are HTML attributes good for storing data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, storage

(Please disregard any security concerns you may have with this approach, I have a already taken more than enough precautions to make sure that there are no blatant vulnerabilities with this approach)

In PHP, I have many values in a table, with a few buttons to perform javascript functions associated with that row.

**Example:**

```
<td id="row1" record="1">
<button id="button1" onclick="aFunction($(this).parent().attr('record'))">Do a function</button>
</td>
```

Are there any issues (besides those of security) with this approach of storing identification variables in the HTML attributes of a table row?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The W3C endorsed way to accomplish this is through [HTML5 `data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)...

And from a security stand point, if this data is simply the id of the record in the DB...

**You shouldn't be relying on the obscurity of your ids as a security measure.**

As long as you have taken proper access control security measures, it should not, a security risk, **be**.

Comment: Which you can then use `jQuery.data()` to get or set.

Comment: @jondavidjohn not explicitly but I am a person who wants to give credit where credits due especially since the W3C is latching onto to coattails of the WHATWG because XHTML 2 was such a failure... I still upvoted since this a good answer.

Comment: @CoryLarson: `jQuery.data()` doesn't change the underlying attribute when you set a property. It initializes itself with whatever `data-*` attributes are there then stores them internally. Of course, that's not a problem as long as you consistently use `jQuery.data()`.